# Is it possible to add own html class or id to a Microsoft Bot Signin Card?

Tags: c#, botframework

My colleague who is a QA is running some automated tests using Selenium in Visual Studio against a Microsoft Bot that is being run in Microsoft Teams. Now he needs to be able to target a "Signin Card" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference), which shows like this,
[image]

This Signin card is constructed in my C# code by creating an instance of "SigninCard", which takes 2 parameters, one, which is "Text" and the other, which is "Buttons". The constructor only takes 2 parameters.

```
var signinCard = new SigninCard
{
  Text = "Test Sign-in Card",
  Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "This way to Sign-in", 
  value: endPoint, text: $"Copy {loginUrl} into browser if it does not open") },
};
```

Basically he needs to target the button by using an identifier to do so, hence why he has requested a class or id be put on it. However, the construction of this element is supposedly done by the bot framework. Im not aware of any properties I can set to put a class or id on this button unless anyone knows how this can be achieved or if I can go about this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, without modification to the SDK, no.

However, as the SDK is open source, you could create your own class, copying the [Microsoft.Bot.Schema.SigninCard](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Schema/SigninCard.cs) class, adding the properties you need / want to it. Then, modify the [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ActivityFactory](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ActivityFactory.cs#L23) class to include the custom signin card. Lastly, you would build your own assembly of it that would then be used in place of the assembly available from the SDK.